# ArchUnit: How to get gradle to execute the tests?

Tags: gradle, archunit

I have a gradle project where I've added the `archunit-junit5` dependency and written some test classes with `@ArchTest`s. These get picked up by IntelliJ.

How do I get *gradle* to execute them?

I've found the [`com.societegenerale.commons:arch-unit-gradle-plugin`](https://github.com/societe-generale/arch-unit-gradle-plugin) but that seems to need configuration in the gradle file.

I just want gradle to pick up the tests I already have in the `test/java` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle should pick up `@ArchTest`s with `archunit-junit5` if you `useJUnitPlatform()`.
https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit-Examples/tree/main/example-junit5 shows a quite minimal working example.

Comment: Please give more details that allow us to reproduce your issue if that doesn't work for you.